# NVIDIA X Server Settings Not Saving

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a GT 630 (2GB DDR2 Ram, PCIe16, HDMI, DVI, And VGA)
Im running Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS 64Bit With Gnome Shell.

I have the "NVIDIA bianary driver - version 331.113 from nvidia-331 (proprietary, tested)" Driver, if i use the X.Org.X server Driver it doesnt have options in the NVIDIA X Server settings application.

But my problem is when i go to set any setings, spisificly the main monitor on boot. it works when i set it, but once i restart it goes back to my 2nd monitor, once i log on the taskbar is on the main monitor. but thats gnome overriding it. i want nvidia to use HDMI first insted of VGA.

If you need more Skype me @ TheShayBox